# How to find the minimum number of pairs?

Tags: combinatorics

> Suppose there are 25 football player who has been chosen for participating in countries largest football league.There are 7 teams in that country.Those player were split into 7 teams in some manner so that each team has at least one participant.Find the minimum  number of pairs of friends that could have formed by the end of the league.

The way i did :

1st team:4 players

2nd team:4 players

3rd team:4 players

4th team:4 players

5th team:3 players

6th team:3 players

7th team:3 players

Min number of pair of friends can be formed:$ 4c2+4c2+4c2+4c2+3c2+3c2+3c2=6+6+6+6+3+3+3=33$

My question is how can we do it other than using combinatorics because if the number of player is given greater than 100 and the number of team is given greater than 100 then it would be tough to perform the calculation the way i did !Can anyone help me with an equation ,explanation needed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to justify that splitting the players as equally as possible will result in the smallest number of pairs.  Your answer has that characteristic, so it seems you believe it.  If you assume that one team has at least two players more than another, you can show that the number of pairs is decreased if the team with more players gives one to the other.

Having done that, you can just divide the number of players by the number of teams to find the number of players per team.  In your example $25=7\cdot 3 +4$ so three teams got three players and four teams get four.  There are only two numbers of players, so compute the number of pairs per team in each case, multiply and add.  It won't be much calculation.

Comment: So what if i take 40 instead of 25 , 40=7*5+5 which i cannot relate with your explanation can you explain me for number 40 again ?

Comment: I'll use $39=7\cdot 5+4$ to avoid having two $5$s that can be confused.  This says there are at least $5$ players per team, with $4$ teams getting a sixth and $7-4=3$ teams having only $5$.  The minimum number of pairs is $4{6 \choose 2}+3{5 \choose 2}=4\cdot 15+3\cdot 10=90$